# How do I format an exponent?

Tags: c#, math

```
public partial class frmValidate : Form
{
    const double ANNUAL_INTEREST_RATE = .05;
    const double YEARS = 10;

    public frmValidate()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double dblFutureValue;
        if (double.TryParse(txtFutureValue.Text, out dblFutureValue))
        {
        }
    }

    private void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtFutureValue.Clear();
        lblPresentValue.Text = "";
        txtFutureValue.Focus();           
    }

    private void frmValidate_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblInterestRate.Text = ANNUAL_INTEREST_RATE.ToString();
        lblYears.Text = YEARS.ToString();
    }

    private void PresentValue (double dblFutureValue)
    {
        double dblPresentValue;
        dblPresentValue = dblFutureValue / (1 + ANNUAL_INTEREST_RATE) * YEARS;
        dblPresentValue.ToString("C");
    }
}
```

I have a method called Present Value, and the formula is supposed to be:

```
PresentValue = Future Value / (1+r)^n
```

I know you use the `Math.Pow()` method, but I just cant figure out where to put it.

Comment: Read [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow(v=vs.110).aspx)..? `Pow(x, y)` raises `x` to the `y` power. In your case `x` is `(1 + r)` and `y` is `n`.

Answer (score 2):

```
private void PresentValue (double dblFutureValue)
    {
        double dblPresentValue;
        double r = Math.Pow(1 + ANNUAL_INTEREST_RATE,YEARS);
        dblPresentValue = dblFutureValue / r;
        dblPresentValue.ToString("C");
    }
```

Comment: thank you. Im new to codding and didnt really understand where it went.